# EMI due diligence

Tags: pwm, emc, led-strip

I had an idea to use the World Semi WS 2801IC used for addressable led strips with a power mosfet driver so that each address can be tied to a high current (~1-1.5A) load.  The chip indicates the PWM period is 2.5kHz (http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2801.pdf) and I am planning to use a pullup on the MOSFET gate that results in a 1.569 us switching time constant with the gate capacitance. The strips can be fairly long (as much as 5m each).  When I lay the strips out, there would also be wires about this length to carry the led leads back to my control board.

I would like to know what I need to do to make sure this will not interfere with any navigation or emergency communications, and thus cause a safety issue.  For the time being I plan to be doing this in a garage to experiment.  My primary concern is that I cause a problem before knowing the circuit is capable of doing so.

Comment: I should note I am open to alternative drive methods as well.  I know I can do constant current with op-amp output to FET and feedback through current sense resistor, but it seems like there will be FET dissipation problems at the lower current levels.  I know the WS2801's are already used in addressable strips, presumably without issue, though maybe emi is not a significant problem if ICs have random phase.

Answer (score 3):

You should be fine, your edge rates are very low (representing ~ 600 KHz) and with a general rule of thumb that a radiator must be at least 1/10 of a wavelength you'd need to be longer than 47 m. Just make sure you're not generating harmonics, which means keeping the edges rates low.  Make sure that you keep the return currents close to the strip to minimize loop area to reduce magnetic mode coupling.

Comment: There is a small loop area always depending on how the LED strip pcb is laid out, but I was thinking I should twist the wires leading to control pcb.  Someone mentioned to me that with the 1.569us time constant I may be leaving FETs in linear region too long.  I did a calc and it looks like this would be a problem if I want to be able to handle 1.5A.  I don't want to add the push-pull transistors on each channel as they suggested due to cost/space, so will probably decrease pullup resistance by half (leading to 23.5m max by your rule of thumb) and decrease current rating accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a 'legal' answer, or anything that would stand up in court.

I do have a cheap easy approach, which *might* help detect a potential problem.

I sometimes use my old analogue radio (in my alarm clock) and tune it to different radio stations. I try long wave (though there doesn't seem to be much to tune to) and medium wave. I'd try FM too, which was the radio spectrum used by emergency services.

Switch on the gizmo, a metre or two away. If the radio loses the station, and sounds like noise, I may have a problem.

A good oscilloscope would pick this up too, and do a more useful job. but it is so easy to have the radio on :-)

Very crude I accept, and probably not reliable enough. However, it might alert you to a real problem early and cheaply. It won't prove their is no problem.

In the UK, we have EM testing companies, but they charge quite a lot of money. You wouldn't approach one until you have your project close to a product stage, by which time fixing problems is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is an EMI receiver.

The next best thing is a spectrum analyzer, which can be rented for little money if you don't need a top-of-the-line model (hint: you don't), and a telescope antenna.

If you have a digital oscilloscope, fetching data and running an FFT should also work.

Testing for emissions is best done by frequency domain analysis, because it allows you to find signals at or below the resolution of the detection equipment -- the FFT will amplify differences in the noise distribution of your sampled data.